# How to go from a->b b->c...y->z on python 3.5

Tags: python, encryption, python-3.5, caesar-cipher

I am trying to create a program which changes a->b b->c...y->z on a long text. The only language i know is python. All the similar questions I have seen only work on the last character but I am trying to do it to a whole document so instead of hs going to ht i want hs going to it. This is for a cryptogram solver which works on fake names.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is define an array containing the letters of the alphabet (a to z) and then iterate over your string and produce a new one where each character is replaced by the next element in the array, modulo the array's length so that z loop back to a.

```
alphabet = [chr(i) for i in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1)]

new_string = ''

for char in my_string:
    new_string += alphabet[(alphabet.index(char) + 1) % len(alphabet)]
```